# Compare two columns from two different files and display output in new file

Tags: command-line, scripts, awk, source-code

file1.txt

```
psid   task   status 

1       a1      run
2       a2      run
3       a3      stop
4       a4      run     
5       a5      stop
```

file2.txt

```
a1      stop
a2      stop
a3      run
a4      run 
a5      stop
```

output -

```
task    status      ok
a1      run         nok
a2      run         nok
a3      stop        nko
a4      run         ok  
a5      stop        ok
```

I would like to compare the task and status column from file1 and file2 and display data in a new file with task and status and the string as if it's equal then "ok" if not "nok"

This is what I tried, but it is working for false condition but for true also it displays false.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ arr[$2]=$2 $1; next } 
{ print $0, (arr[$2]==$2 $3?"ok":"nok") }' OFS=, file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: @shubham patil: Homework?

Comment: it is workinf for false condition but for true also it is display false

Comment: I have updated it in question thank you @pLumo

Answer (score 1):

So, lets take a look at what you tried:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ arr[$2]=$2 $1; next }
{ print $0, (arr[$2]==$2 $3?"ok":"nok") }' OFS=, file2.txt file1.txt
```

- `-F,` sets the field delimiter to comma, which if you look at your files is wrong.
- `arr[$2]=$2 $1` Your key field in `file2.txt` is `$1`, not `$2`.
- The order of fields you assign to your `arr` is switched. In first part you assign `$2 $1`, the second part is `$2 $3`, but should be `$3 $2` then. Or vice versa, the first part `$1 $2` --
  **But** why not assign only the run/stop value, that should be enough!

---

So the closest working version to your solution would be:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ arr[$1]=$2 $1; next }
{ print $0, (arr[$2]==$3 $2?"ok":"nok") }' OFS=, file2.txt file1.txt
```

But I'd go with this:

```bsh
awk '
    NR==FNR{ arr[$1]=$2;next;}
    FNR>2{ print $2,$3,(arr[$2]==$3?"ok":"nok") }
 ' file2.txt file1.txt
```